# Displaying reports for files using Python

Tags: python, subprocess, output

Question about general possibilities using Python here, I don't really know enough about programming to know whether it's something that's doable, and if so, how do I go about it.

I have a program which is a simple desktop program, which you load files into. The program can then output various properties of the thing that's in the file, and depending on what you ask it to do will output a report. It outputs the report in text format, but not as a file, and instead actually, just in the program itself displays the report. Like this:

[image: Output]

My question is that if I want to get this text output for a large number of files, I'm currently manually loading the files individually into the program making the report, copying this to a text file, and saving the text file.

Basically I want to know whether it's extremely difficult to get Python to do this for me, or not. If it is doable, are the resources available for me to read about how it might be done? Are there conditions about being able to run my program and various commands from the Python command box?

Hope my question's clear enough. Sorry if it's a bit garbled.

Comment: Am I right to understand that the application you are working with (can you name it?) is not something that you have developed or have any control over? What you're trying to do effectively is to automate the process of copying and pasting data out of it?

Although everything is possible, this sounds to me like it would be a very difficult task, unless the application offers some kind of scripting interface. Could you elaborate on what you mean by the "Python command box"? Is that a part of this application, or do you just mean Python running separately?

Comment: It's an application called GENIE. It's some gamma acquisition software. I did not develop it, and I certainly have no control over it. That's exactly right, I'm trying to find a way of automating that. The application does not have a scripting interface. I'm afraid the question itself betrays my lack of programming understaning in general: I didn't know whether this sort of thing would be easy or hard. When I say Python command box I just mean Python running separately, yes.

Comment: It is yeah. I've seen that description before too, but I've no idea how I'm supposed to run it from the command line. I can't find any documentation anywhere.

Comment: I just found this!! http://www.qsl.net/k/k0ff/Genie/GENIE2K/pdfs/docs/S561%20Batch%20Tools%20Support.pdf I'd previously been searching "run GENIE from command line" But searching "GENIE 2000 batch procedure" got it. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

The tricky part here is

> The program can then output various properties of the thing that's in the file, and depending on what you ask it to do will output a report.

Basically, if the desktop application you use has a command line interface, it is possible and relatively easy.
If this program has command line option to open a document and output a report in any format (print the report on the standard output, write it into a file on the disk, etc.), you can call that commands from a script python for each files you set in a list.

If your software doesn't have a CLI (Command Line Interface), it might be possible but more diffficult. In that case, you have to automate actions by using a library that will emulate clicks on the Window of you software (1. Click on Open 2. Click, click, click to select the file to load 3. Click on the button to generate a report etc.) It's a pain, but it can be considered.

You will find plenty of resources to learn by yourself how to code a python script. You will probably need to learn about lists, loops, files manipulations and maybe the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) library which will let you call any command from your python script.

I suggest you to start with Python3 instead of Python2 because it has a better support for unicode that could quickly become an issue if you have non ascii characters in your input files or in reports from your software.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Perhaps I gave the wrong impression - I have experience with Python! And programming in general. I just count myself as pretty far behind you guys on here. There is no command line interface, so as you suggest it might be more difficult than that. Is there a recommended way to go about automating actions through Python? As you say, that sounds painful, but the process of doing this all by hand is, similarly, rather painful.

Comment: I don't have any experience in scripts that emulate clicks on a GUI, so I can't suggest anything about that. I can search on the internet but you will find the same results by yoursefl for sure

Answer (score 1):

If the only way you can get report is selecting and copy/pasting it from program GUI, the situation just begs for AutoIt instead of Python.
With Python it would be much more difficult. Unless you want to improve your python knowledge or course...

Simulating keypresses, you can open specific file in program (through sending ctrl+o or alt and navigating file menu). Simulating mouse or keypress - start report generation. Then simulate a mouse click in text area, and perform something like:
(just a skeleton of script, probably need to be modified to suit your situation and needs)

```
send("^{a}^{c}") ; to select all and copy (if these keys are supported in this program
$text = ClipGet() ; get contents of clipboard
$fout = FileOpen("somefile.txt",2)
FileWrite($fout,$text)
FileClose($fout)
```

To fully automate the task, in script you can get a list of source files in specific folder, and run this macro for each of them, automatically naming resulting txt files.